# Alguno sabe como solucionar este error? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript

soy novato en JavaScript, y tengo un problema con un formulario súper sencillo que he estado haciendo me tira este error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null adjunto mí código de JavaScript por aquello:

```
function tomaDatos() {
$tomadeNombre = document.getElementById("nombreCliente").value;
$tomadeCedula = document.getElementById("númeroCédula").value;
$tomaMetodoPago = document.getElementById("Pago").value;
$tomaProducto = document.getElementById("TarjetaGráfica1").value;
$tomaProducto2 = document.getElementById("TarjetaGráfica2").value;
$tomaProducto3 = document.getElementById("Control").value;

let dato = "";

if ($tomaProducto.checked) {
    dato = $tomaProducto.value;
}else if($tomaProducto2.checked){
    dato=$tomaProducto2.value; 
}else{
    dato=$tomaProducto3.value; 
}
```

let mensajeFinal=alert('El usuario'+$tomadeNombre+'ha elegido el siguiente producto en descuento:'+dato);

```
}
```